# Why is JQuery slower on Chrome 10 than on Chrome 8?

Tags: jquery, browser, google-chrome, performance

According to the [JQuery 1.5 release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/01/31/jquery-15-released/), the speed performance charts show that Chrome 8 is faster for the mentioned JQuery methods `children()`, `prev()`, `next()`.

I wonder how that would be, since recently Chrome reported they are using the new [crankshaft javascript optimization engine](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/12/new-crankshaft-for-v8.html)

Screenshot where you can see the Chrome 8 columns are taller than Chrome 10 (and thus faster):

[image: JQuery 1.5 performance screenshot]

So the question is: If the numbers reported here is true, then why would Chrome 10 be a slower browser than the mainstream Chrome 8?

Comment: Isn't 10 still a dev release?

Comment: @Pekka, sure it is a developers release. But my assumption is that they will release it to make the browser faster -- not slower:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Chrome 10 is still beta?

Comment: Even if it is in beta, i would assume they build new releases to show off faster features. I am looking for more specific information -- in case somebody has knowledge as to what exactly makes it slower

Answer (score -1):

Is the next version of any software ever faster than it's predecessor?

Unless a release involves a major refactoring or redesign, it's probably got the same engine with more stuff hanging off it. That means slower.

Comment: As referenced in the question Chrome is moving to a new JavaScript engine. `I wonder how that would be, since recently Chrome reported they are using the new crankshaft javascript optimization engine`

Comment: My bad. In reading about crankshaft, I thought they meant it had been introduced in Chrome 8, when actually the engine is called V8. Anyway, sounds like Crankshaft is not necessarily faster for all operations.